# Print current command with echo?

Tags: bash, echo

I have a script that I copyed in
/usr/bin/ups

In this script I print usage with this:

```
if [ ! $# == 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
   exit
fi
```

when I run command "ups" I get this:

> Usage: /usr/bin/ups {start|stop|restart|status}

How can I print usage like this:

> Usage: ups {start|stop|restart|status}

The easyest way will be to do this:

```
if [ ! $# == 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: ups {start|stop|restart|status}"
   exit
fi
```

but if some day I change the name of this file the usage text will be the same as before (ups).

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `basename`:

```
echo "Usage: $(basename $0) {start|stop|restart|status}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the

```
$0
```

to

```
${0##*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
echo "Usage: ${0##*/} {start|stop|restart|status}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[basename](http://man.cx/basename):

```
basename /usr/bin/ups  # outputs ups
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could do it like this:

```
COMMAND_NAME=${0##*/}
if [ "$(which $COMMAND_NAME 2> /dev/null)" != "$0" ]; then
    COMMAND_NAME=$0  
fi

if [ ! $# == 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $COMMAND_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
   exit
fi
```

Which will use the [which](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/which.1.php) command to determine if you're running the program from the PATH. Then display `Usage: ups {start|stop|restart|status}`, but if you use a relative path to it it will display that path instead: `Usage: ../../usr/bin/ups {start|stop|restart|status}`.

That is handy because if you ever take it out of the PATH it will still work correctly.